# Add attribute to JS object specific place

Tags: javascript

I want to add attribute to a JS object, but in a custom place, After a given attribute.

```
var me = {
    name: "myname",
    age: "myage",
    bday: "mybday"
};
me["newAt"] = "kkk"; //this adds at the end of the object
```

Is there a way to specify the object (`me`), an attribute(`age`) in it and add a new attribute(`newAt`) right after the specified one? A better way than doing string operations?

```
var newMe = {
    name: "myname",
    age: "myage",
    newAt: "newAttr",
    bday: "mybday"
}
```

**UPDATE**: (Since people are more focused on why I'm asking this than actually answering it) 
I'm working on a drawable component based on user input - which is a JS object. And it has the ability to edit it - so when the user adds a new property based on "add new node" on the clicked node, and I was thinking of adding the new node right after it. And I want to update the data accordingly.

Comment: why do you need to have the property at the specified index? what do you mean by that `A better way than doing string operations`?

Comment: this approach is wrong in any language. you should not rely on order.

Comment: At least related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JSON. I've removed the tag.

Comment: *"Since people are more focused on why I'm asking this than actually answering it"* Both of the answers you received prior to your edit adding that answered the question head-on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution I could find was to iterate through the keys of the parent and keep pushing them to form a clone of the parent. But to additionally push the new object if the triggered key is met.

```js
var myObj = {
  child1: "data1",
  child2: "data2",
  child3: "data3",
  child4: "data4"
};

var a = (function addAfterChild(data, trigChild, newAttribute, newValue) {
  var newObj = {};
  Object.keys(data).some(function(k) {
    newObj[k] = data[k];
    if (k === trigChild) {
      newObj[newAttribute] = newValue;
    }
  });
  return newObj;
})(myObj, "child3", "CHILD", "VALUE");

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(a);
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript object is an **unordered** list of properties. The order is not defined and may vary when using with an iterator like `for in`. You shouldn't base your code on the order of properties you see in debugger or console.

Comment: *"JavaScript object is an unordered list of properties."* This is no longer true as of ES2015. But you still shouldn't rely on order, even though ordre is now there.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thanks, glad I answered, otherwise I wouldn't found that out :). Do you have any link at hand where I can read about that?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32149345/157247) covers it. There's a better one somewhere that I haven't found yet.

Comment: Thanks, if you find it, please drop it here)

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I wouldn't say that particular statement is untrue. It's true that when the keys are enumerated it is done in a well-defined order, but the object itself is still unordered.

Comment: @SachiDangalla, what can I add to my answer to make it acceptable?

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript objects **do**, as of ES2015, have an order to their properties, although that order is only guaranteed to be used by certain operations (`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, `Reflect.ownKeys`, etc.), notably **not** `for-in` or `Object.keys` for legacy reasons. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties) for details.

But you should not *rely* on that order, there's no point to it, it's more complicated than it seems initially, and it's very hard to manipulate (you basically have to create a new object to set the order of its properties). If you want order, use an array.

Re your edit:

> I'm working on a drawable component based on user input - which is a JS object. And it has the ability to edit it - so when the user adds a new property based on "add new node" on the clicked node, and I was thinking of adding the new node right after it. And I want to update the data accordingly.

The best way to do that is, if you want a specific order, keep the order of keys in an array and use that to show the object.

While you *could* use ES2015's property order for it, to do so you'd have to:

- Require your users use a truly ES2015-compliant browser, because this cannot be shimmed/polyfilled
- Destroy the object and recreate it adding the properties in the specific order you want each time you add a property
- Forbid properties that match the specification's definition of an array index

It's just much more work and much more fragile than keeping the order in an array.